# build an array from two tables joined

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to display a list op car options on a page. Each option has a parent category.
for this I use two tables :

option_parents

```
id---parent_name
1     body
2     safety
```

option_children

```
id---parent_id--option_name
1       1         3-door
2       1         2-door
3       2         ABS
4       3         airbags
```

on the page I want to list them by parent_name. For example

---

BODY

---

3-door

2-door

---

SAFETY

---

abs

Airbags

I gues for this I would need to create an array and loop through it. But I am unsure how to approach this. I can do a query like this :

```
SELECT t1.option_name
     , t2.id
     , t2.parent_name 
  FROM option_children AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN option_parents AS t2
    ON t2.id = t1.parent_id
```

but that gives me as result:

```
option_name---id---parent_name
2door          1    body
3door          1    body
abs            2    safety
airbags        2    safety
```

and I cant figure out how to loop through this so I get basically and array like

```
body=> 3-door, 2door
safety=>abs,airbags
```

---

Comment: If you're using PDO, you can use the fetch mode [PDO::FETCH_GROUP](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_GROUP)

Comment: IMHO too short for an answer: `foreach($rows as $row) {$groupedData[$row->parent_name][] = $row->option_name;}`

Answer (score 0):

thx Paul for getting me on the right track.

```
function list_options(){

$mysql_query = "SELECT t1.option_name
     , t2.id
     , t2.parent_name 
  FROM option_children AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN option_parents AS t2
    ON t2.id = t1.parent_id";
$query = $this->_custom_query($mysql_query);
$result = $query->result();



foreach($result as $row){
    $groupedData[$row->parent_name][] = $row->option_name;
 }

 return $groupedData;
}
```

lets me loop through it like this :

```
foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
    echo '<dl style="margin-bottom: 1em;">';
    echo "<dt>$key</dt>";
  foreach ($value as $row ) {
        echo "<dd>$row</dd>";
  }
  echo '</dl>';
}
```